# Overriding a class with a JQuery method to insert a style element

Tags: jquery, html, css

There have been many discussions on related topics but not on this specific question. So, please do not jump and mark it as a duplicate without reading the question carefully.

JQuery does not have any method to modify a class (though it has methods to add and remove classes). On that there are many discussions. The question that I have is that suppose there is a class as in

```
      .myclass
      {
        property1: value1;
        property2: value2;
        ...
       }
```

I then, dynamically, using JQuery do something like:

```
     newstyle = "<style type='text/css'>.myclass {property1:newvalue1; property2:                 newvalue2,...} </style>";
     $('head').append(newstyle);
```

Excuse the typos, if any. The questions that I have are:

Question 1: The dynamically defined class appears to override the statically defined myclass. In a way, is that not dynamic class modification? Is there something about this that is not cross-browser or any other pitfalls?

Question 2: Does it override or supplement the statically defined myclass? I mean, what if statically defined myclass has property1 and other properties and dynamically defined myclass has property 2 only. Will the total properties now defined be the Union of the two classes with intersections been overwritten by the dynamically defined class?

Yes, I tried and got different behaviors but I have no base to know what should be expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by [**specificity**](http://blog.jamesmdonnelly.com/what-the-heck-is-specificity/). Your dynamically added style is overriding your existing style as your dynamic CSS is rendered *after* your non-dynamic CSS:

```html
<!-- static style element -->
<style type="text/css">
    .myclass {
        property1: value1;
    }
</style>

<!-- dynamic style element -->
<style type="text/css">
    .myclass {
        property1: value2; /* Same specificity, overrides previous. */
    }
</style>
```

I've created a [**this JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WmyJ7/) to demonstrate this. Here I have a `figure` element with an ID of "example". There is a `figure` selector which sets the `background` property to red and a `figure#example` selector which sets the `color` property to white. I then append a CSS `style` element as you've done which uses the `figure` selector to change the `background` property to green and attempt to change the `color` property to black.

As the `figure#example` selector has greater specificity than the dynamic `figure` selector, only the `background` property is changed.

```html
<!-- static style element -->
<style type="text/css">
    .myclass.myclass { /* Higher specificity selector by duplicating class. */
        property1: value1;
    }
</style>

<!-- dynamic style element -->
<style type="text/css">
    .myclass {
        property1: value2; /* No change as previous has higher specificity. */
    }
</style>
```

If we *prepend* this CSS, the dynamic CSS is added before our static CSS and our static CSS is used as the specificty of our selectors is the same. [**JSFiddle prepend demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WmyJ7/1/):

```html
<!-- dynamic style element -->
<style type="text/css">
    .myclass {
        property1: value1;
    }
</style>

<!-- static style element -->
<style type="text/css">
    .myclass {
        property1: value2; /* Same specificity, overrides previous. */
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and I have accepted your answer. I was precisely looking for the append and prepend distinction. But I do not understand the difference in behavior because you are prepending or appending to the head tag. Why should that distinction (prepend/append) on a higher element have an impact on the styles of a lower-level (child) element?

Comment: The `append` method adds the new style markup to the end of the `head` element whereas the `prepend` method adds the new style markup to the beginning of the `head` element. The C in CSS stands for *cascading*; the styles are read in in a cascading fashion. This means that if we have one selector at the start of our `head` element which adds one value to *property X*, then add an identical selector at the end of our `head` element which adds a different value to *property X*, the property selector will use the new value.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. The presumption here in the example is that the statically defined styles are in the head section. If a style tag is dynamically generated as a child of  a later section and then used by an element in that very parent section/element, will that also take effect to override the statically defined ones in the head section? I would presume Yes. Never tried it but I don't think that style tag, though mostly specified in head section, is disallowed as child of other sections. Right?

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, Does not have pitfalls as such or browser compatibility issues. However, under most circumstances, only a small set of properties need to be changed for any class dynamically. (If not, its not a good way to program CSS)

This can be achieved directly using

```
$('selector').css({"property1": "value1", ...})
```

Also, this ensures only a particular element of interest gets affected while, others remain as it is.

Question 2: The properties now defined will be union of 2 classes with intersections overwritten. Try defining the same class properties one after another and verify.

```
.myclass {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
}
.myclass {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are effectively doing is dynamically converting your original HTML, which would look something like this:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .myclass {
            property1: value1;
            property2: value2;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

...into something that would look like this:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .myclass {
            property1: value1;
            property2: value2;
        }
    </style>

    <style type="text/css">
        .myclass {
            property1: newvalue1;
            property2: newvalue2;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Hence, we end up with two CSS selectors that target the same element (anything having the `myclass` class). CSS [specificity rules](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) dictate that where two properties conflict "the last one wins", so your dynamically added CSS will override anything that went before. However, where there are properties that do not conflict, then the result will be a union of the two CSS rules.

Answer (score 0):

The `C` in CSS stands for "Cascading" which means that css fully supports re-defining classes of styles in the following order

1. Externally referenced stylesheets
2. Locally defined styles (ie `<style>...</style>` in the head as per your example)
3. Locally defined styles (ie `<span style="...">`).

Answer to Q1: There is nothing "static" about a css class, they can be redefined as described above

Answer to Q2: It supplements it. That is to say that if you define the following in an external stylesheet:

```
.myclass{width:100px}
```

and then this locally:

```
 <style>
   .myclass{color:red}
 </style>
```

Then anything marked `myclass` will be 100px and red